# How to find another eigenvector when I have same eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

As in the topic. Let's say I have three eigenvalues, but two of them are equal. For example for $\lambda_1$ I got $v_1$ and how do I find another (I don't know how to write it in English) not 
 lineary related (?) eigenvector if $\lambda_1$ was a double root of characteristic polymonial.

Thanks!

Comment: "not linearly related" = *linearly independent*.

Answer (score 1):

You just solve the linear system of equations $(A - \lambda_1 I)\mathbf{v} = \mathbf{0}$ (using Gaussian elimination for example) and find a basis of linearly independent solutions which will be eigenvectors associated to the eigenvalue $\lambda_1$.